# 403 error when publishing a post in wordpress. Error => Publishing failed. The response is not a valid JSON response

Tags: rest-api, json

I am developing a site for my client and when I try to post a post I get the following error:

"Publishing failed. The response is not a valid JSON response."

Apparently, it's a popular error so I found a lot of solutions for it online. Like updating the permalink structure, removing and readding .htaccess. But, none of it works.

Here is the screenshot of the error.

[image]

It works when I use the classic editor, it also works when I post a post with just the title. The problem seem to be the gutenberg block editor but I need it because I have a block plugin developed for the site.

Also, I found this solution:

[https://www.dreamhost.com/blog/how-to-fix-403-forbidden-error-wordpress/#:~:text=When%20the%20403%20status%20code,specific%20page%20on%20your%20site](https://www.dreamhost.com/blog/how-to-fix-403-forbidden-error-wordpress/#:%7E:text=When%20the%20403%20status%20code,specific%20page%20on%20your%20site).

Maybe it works, but I need to be sure before I tell my client about this.

As per the request, the response section shows this:[image]

Comment: Can you logout, clear cookies and login again. It will start working.

Comment: it would be more useful to show what is in the response tab of the dev tools. if @aftabs solution doesn't help, try also disabling all plugins and reverting to the default theme and try again.

Comment: @Paul, I've added the response tab image. Would really appreciate any help. I've already tried unistalling all themes and plugins.